# HTML Javascript change stylesheet depending by browser width

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to make a different usage of my stylesheets depending if the device is mobile or not.
I would like that my javascript could compare the height and the weight of browser. I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function applyStyle() {
var $ = document; // shortcut
var mobile = 'mobile';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
var desktop = 'desktop';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
    if ($(window).height() > $(window).width()) {
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = mobile;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css/interfacemobile.css';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
else {
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = desktop;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css/interface.css';
    head.appendChild(link);
}}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    applyStyle();
    </script>
```

I think that my error is on calling of script, but I'm not sure because I'm not very skilled with JS.
Thank you very much for the help!

---

Edit:
Now I'm Trying this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkStyle() {
var check = false;
(function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
return check; 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function applyStyle() {
    if (checkStyle()) {
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = mobile;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css/interfacemobile.css';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
else {
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = desktop;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css/interface.css';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    applyStyle();
    </script>
```

### But it doesn't work, why? TT_TT

Edit: The solution for me has been:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isMobile() {
var check = false;
(function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
return check; 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = document; // shortcut
var mobile = 'mobile';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
var desktop = 'desktop';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
function applyStyle() {
    if (isMobile()) {
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = mobile;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css/interfacemobile.css';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
else {
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = desktop;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css/interface.css';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    applyStyle();
    </script>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Did you look at your browser's JavaScript console at all? Try pressing 'F12', it might help you see what's going wrong.

Comment: Now you remove the `var $ = ducment` so you should change also all the  `$` for `document`. Also... use chrome for debugging and open the Developers Tools... F12 or contextmenu > Inspect Element like David Thomas said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in

```
var $ = document; // shortcut
```

and then

```
if ($(window).height() > $(window).width()) {
```

$ is document and you are using it like jQuery

use `window.innerHeight`  `window.innerWidth`

Comment: it works, but if I load the page from a mobile device on landscape mode it loads "desktop" stylesheet. Can js recognize if the device is mobile or not?

Comment: can and can't... there is several ways to do it... check  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser) also search in google the `<meta viewport="">` tag and `media queries`

Comment: I've solved with the script in your link! Goodjob my frind, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use CSS media queries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 700px)" href="css/narrow.css" />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 901px)" href="css/narrow.css" />
```

OR, if you really want to use javascript, you can use this:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    } else {
       $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/wide.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: I need an universal manner for recognize all the resolutions. Usually mobile devices have the height > width!

Comment: You're question said depending on browser width, so I answered as such. I'm sure what I have posted can be modified to work for height also.

Comment: Of course, it works also for height. I intended that my stylesheets doesn't depending from a specified dimension, but also if height>width!

Comment: Ah, I get you. You can also do that with this also. Use the Javascript i've got, also get the height and do an `if (width<height) { $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/narrow.css");}`